# Is there a DDP request monitoring tool for Chrome or Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, meteor, ddp

I am working on Meteor projects, which provide real-time updates by DDP (Distributed Data Protocol). I wish to monitor those requests within the browser.

Is there any tool to allow monitoring DDP requests?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As DDP is based on WebSockets, you can actually monitor the transmitted data of those requests within the Chrome DevTools. To do so just switch the *Network* tab and then choose *websocket* from the list and click the *Frames* tab: 
[image: Chrome DevTools websocket screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

There is a Chrome extension that adds monitoring of Meteor DDP traffic to the Dev Tools: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ddp-monitor/ippapidnnboiophakmmhkdlchoccbgje

Source code: https://github.com/thebakeryio/meteor-ddp-monitor

Answer (score 0):

[Meteor Toys](https://meteor.toys) has a DDP monitor that logs to the console - which lets you view DDP data in any browser.